# AJAX JSON array to php not showing up

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Ok guys this question has been asked many times but I have looked through all of those answers and attempted to do what they have said to no avail. According to all the posts I have read and everything I know this should be working and I have no idea why it is not.  What I have is a script running some javascript parsing out names into an array.  I am then trying to send that array, through ajax, to the php server so I can get those variables in php.  I have looked at the google debugger and it posts fine but when I try to access the variable via $_POST['name'] nothing shows up.  When I do an if to check if name is set using isset nothing happens as well.  Im completely at a loss here.  Here's the code.  It displays beginning and end but not middle.  I have spent too long on this and just do not understand why it is not working.  Thanks in advance.

```
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $("#teamSubmit").click(function() {
            //Code here
            //Loop through all colmns in team div
            var teamArray = [];
            $("#teams .team .column").each(function(index, element){
                //Loop through all items in the column
                var $this = $(this);
                //console.log($(this));
                //console.log("Hello");
                thisTeam = '';
                $this.children(".portlet").each(function(index1, element){
                    //thisTeam += ($(this).find(".portlet-header").text();
                    //console.log("Inside .portlet");
                    //console.log('Length =' + ($(this).length - 1) + ' Index =' + index1);
                    if(($this.children(".portlet").length - 1) === index1){

                        thisTeam += ($(this).find(".portlet-header")).text();
                        //console.log("New team");
                    }
                    else{
                        thisTeam += ($(this).find(".portlet-header")).text() + ",";

                    }   

                });
                console.log(thisTeam);
                teamArray[index] = thisTeam;

            });
            //console.log(thisTeam);
            //console.log(teamArray);
            jsonArray = JSON.stringify(teamArray);
            $("#teams").html("");
            console.log(jsonArray);


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'settings.php',
                data: {json : jsonArray},
                //data: jsonArray,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    //alert("success!");
                    console.log(jsonArray);
                }
            });


        //Grab javascript array and query and update the db
        <?php
            //echo "console.log('begin '" . isset($_POST['json']) .");";
            //$test = $_POST['jsonArray'];
            //echo $test;
            if(isset($_POST['json'])){
                //$array = $_POST['json'];
                $teamMembers = json_decode($_POST['json']);
                //echo "<script> console.log($teamMembers); </script>";

                echo "console.log('middle');";
                //echo "$teamMembers";

                //Get highest T_ID and increment by 1

                //Loop through insert into SEA_TEAMS

                //Loop through insert into SEA_TEAM_USER

            }

            echo "console.log('end');";

        ?>


});
```

});

Comment: Is the script you are showing settings.php?

Comment: It is part of a file called settings.php but it is not the full file

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` check what you actully get

Comment: Why `JSON.stringify()`? jQuery can pass the Object, like `data:{json:teamArray}`.

Comment: Why are you looking for jsonArray console.log(jsonArray); on success? It should be console.log(data); Is data not displaying anything?

Comment: If your ajax function posts to the same script that is outputting HTML (which i presume is), it will not work. HTML is outputted before your php response. Your ajax function will not be able to read.

Comment: Also, you need the PHP in a file by itself, not along with the javascript. Another thing to do is print_r($_POST); in php to see if POST returns anything at all.

Comment: print_r($_POST) returns Array( [num_projects] => 1 [num_teams] =>3 [createTeams] => Create)  Which were all earlier variables.  I was checking jsonArray just to test it, data outputs fine.

Comment: So would adding the php to a separate file work?

Comment: Lets say its one more step closer to correctness :)

Comment: Well after hours of working on it I finally got it too work, I added it to a different file and had to remove the dataType: 'json' as that seems to be what was screwing it up (though it was a combination of the two as I tried removing it before with no luck.  Thanks guys :)